# Module Not found - Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter

When I run the following code in jupyter I am thrown a module note found error. but when i run the import function in python it works without any errors. The jupyter version i have is 4.4.0 but in anaconda navigator it shows 5.3.0.

```
import plotly

ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-6361d2547ebc> in <module>
----> 1 import plotly

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: using pip install plotly

Comment: Are you running jupyter notebook from within Anaconda or from the command line? There might be some installation problems with different paths for modules installed by pip and by (ana)conda which lead not only to different versions of jupyter but also of (not installed or found) plotly. I do not have any experience in using (ana)conda in parallel to a 'normal' Python installation, but you might want to double-check the installed modules and their installation paths. Is the PYTHONPATH part of your PATH env variable? Which OS are you running on?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @albert you are right. it was the problem of anaconda not recognizing the plotly. I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed plotly using pip install plotly but it required restarting as anaconda failed to recognize the installation

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following command in anaconda prompt?

```
conda install -c plotly plotly
```

then import again, hope this can help you